# How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I recently read this article:
http://coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/

I would like to know if is possible apply lowercase routes in ASP.NET Web Forms.

If yes.. How? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [IIS Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) and that has a route build in to enforce lower case URLs

this will add a web.config rule to control this